# Footers not appearing tanstack react table

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

Version: `"@tanstack/react-table": "^8.2.6",`

I'm trying to add footers to my table and I can't get them to render anything. If I make the footer text static with a set value it will appear, however when I try and implement the same way I implement headers it won't render any values.
No warnings/errors are appearing in chrome dev tools or inn VSCode This is my footer code

```
<tfoot>
  {table.getFooterGroups().map((footerGroup) => {
    <tr key={footerGroup.id} className={el`footer-row`}>
      {footerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
        return (
          <th
            key={header.id}
            colSpan={header.colSpan}
            className={el`footer-cell`}
          >
          {header.isPlaceholder ? null : (
            <div>
              {flexRender(
                header.column.columnDef.footer,
                header.getContext()
              )}
            </div>
          )}
          </th>
        );
      })}
    </tr>
  })}
</tfoot>
```

My `useReactTable` hook

```
const table = useReactTable<T>({
  data: p.data,
  columns: p.columns,
  getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
  debugTable: true,
});
```

Footer implementation at a component level:

```
footer: () => {
  return <Text className={el`table-row`}>Totals:</Text>;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your `map` function does not return nothing at all.

> some functions use parentheses () while others use braces {} . This key difference is that parentheses will implicitly return the last statement while braces require an explicit return statement.

```js
{table.getFooterGroups().map((footerGroup) => (
  <tr key={footerGroup.id} className={el`footer-row`}>
  //...
  </tr>
)}
```

or :

```js
{table.getFooterGroups().map((footerGroup) => {
 return (
  <tr key={footerGroup.id} className={el`footer-row`}>
  //...
  </tr> )
})}
```